# Verb agreement after 'that'

Tags: grammar

I just looked up the word *'avalanche'* in Longman Contemporary and it gives this definition:

> a large mass of snow, ice, and rocks that falls down the side of a mountain

Why does does the verb that follows *'that'* ends with an 's' ? Here, *'falls'*.

Shouldn't *'fall'* agree with what is preceded before 'that' i.e. 'snow, ice, rocks'. Becasuse 'rocks' is plural, isn't it? Grammar, I think, says the verb after a relative pronoun must agree with the nouns before the relative prounoun.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the **box** of chocolate pieces **sits** in the sun, its
>   contents will melt.

*of chocolate pieces* modifies **box**.

Singular **box** is the subject of the verb **sits**.

> If the **mass** of rocks **is** dislodged, **it** will crash down the
>   mountainside.

You could probably say "*they* will crash down" without a problem, because antecedents of pronouns have more freedom to be semantic; but "*are* dislodged" would be much closer to being ungrammatical.

Comment: Yea, thank you guys . That was a rookie learner's mistake 

Answer (score 3):

The agreement here is with "mass" not with "snow, ice and rocks". Since mass is the subject.

edit: I wonder what really would happen if you did have "fall". I think then the agreement would be with "snow, ice and rocks" thus changing the sentence structure and making all of "of snow, ice, and rocks that fall down the side of a mountain" one adjective phrase? I think that works fine though it seems strange?

Comment: Is mass a group noun like team, band, or group?